# Who was in the Fields committee for ICM 1962 (the first appointed by IMU)?

Tags: ho.history-overview, conferences

Traditionally, at the presentation of the Fields medals at the ICM opening ceremony, the composition of the Fields medal committee is disclosed. This information can be found in the first volume of the respective ICM Proceedings (for older ICM, somewhat hidden in the presentation speech of the chair). That is, except for the [1962 ICM at Stockholm](https://www.mathunion.org/fileadmin/ICM/Proceedings/ICM1962.1/ICM1962.1.ocr.pdf), the first for which the Fields Committee was appointed via IMU). It is only clear that Nevanlinna (who gave the presentation speech) was the chair:

> After an interval, Professor Nevanlinna in his capacity of chairman of
>   the  Fields  Medals  Committee,  read the report of the Committee 
>   which was as  follows: [..] The  problem of suggesting names for the
>   award of the Fields  medals has, since the last  congress, been
>   entrusted to the International Mathematical  Union. To  prepare the
>   names at this Congress in Stockholm, the Union  appointed a Fields 
>   medals  committee.  This  committee has the honour to make  known its
>   decision  here.

Some more details are given in the Secretary's report:

> The  scientific  programme  was  drawn  up  in  close  cooperation 
>   with  the   International  Mathematical  Union,  which  for  this 
>   purpose  nominated   a    Consultative  Committee  with  Professor
>   G. de Rham as  chairman.   The    Swedish  representatives  in  charge
>   of the  scientific  programme  were  Professors L.  Gårding,  L. 
>   Carleson  and  L. Hörmander.   Thus  a  first  meeting  was held in 
>   Zurich in November  1960 followed  by  a meeting in Düsseldorf in
>   January  1961. As  a  result  of  these  two  meetings the 
>   "International  Fields  Committee",  that  elects  the  two  prize 
>   winners, was  constituted.  Furthermore  a  list  was made  of 
>   speakers to  be invited  to deliver  one-hour  addresses  on  chosen 
>   topics  in  different   fields  of  mathematics.

From this passage, one might guess that there was an overlap of the Fields and the Program Committee (which would be a historical exception), but I couldn't find more explicit information in the volume. Does someone know more about the composition of the committee?

Answer (score 3):

[Fields Medal Prize Committee 1962](https://www.mathunion.org/imu-awards/fields-medal)

- R. Nevanlinna (chair)
- P.S. Aleksandrov
- E. Artin
- S.-S. Chern
- C. Chevalley
- H. Whitney
- K. Yosida

Only Aleksandrov was also in the IMU consultative committee, the other members were not. For the record, the 1962 consultative committee was chaired by de Rham, with IMU members Aleksandrov, Chandrasekharan, Eckmann, Hodge, Hopf, Montgomery, and Morse, and local Swedish members Carleson, Frostman, Gårding, Hörmander, and Pleijel.

Comment: Many thanks, and please apologize for the too elementary question - obviously, I missed to scroll further down at the IMU Fields prize site, and went lost in the past ICM section. That was of great help!